# Call function after AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have jQuery script that helps me to mark rows in table. Also i have AJAX function that allows me to load additional data to this table. My idea is to call Picker function every time after AJAX used to let this data to be marked as well. It works, but very unstable - i can mark some blocks of loaded data, and can't mark other. And i can't catch where i am wrong.

```
<script>
var Picker = function() { // This is marker script
        $(".query, .schedule_query_table_highlight").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "schedule_query_table_highlight") {
            $(this)

.removeClass("schedule_query_table_highlight");
            $(this).addClass("query");
        }
        else {
        $(this).removeClass("query");
        $(this).addClass("schedule_query_table_highlight");
        }
        });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    Picker();   
    $("#more").click(function(){
    $(".more_space").load("inquery_ajax.php?date=" + curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date, function(){
            Picker();
        });         
        $(".more_space").addClass("loaded" + days);
        $(".more_space").removeClass("more_space");
        $(".loaded" + days).after("<x class=more_space></x>");
        $("#more").insertBefore(".more_space");
    });
});
</script>
```

UPD: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t7z8a4xp/2)

Comment: `$("#more").insertBefore(".more_space")` adds to page several elements with same `id`, which is a bad idea. Also, `$("#more").click` will not work for dynamically created elements.

Comment: You should probably create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) reproducing your problem, so that it will be possible to fix all errors.

Comment: You need to use event delegation with `on()` instead of `click()`. http://api.jquery.com/on/ And as @Regent said, you cannot have duplicate id's or you will continue to have problems.

Comment: @Regent, but at the same time we have only one .more_space element, as  with  `$(".more_space").removeClass("more_space");` we delete this class from previous one, no?

Comment: @Bullwinkle let's imagine you have two elements with class "more_space". You add class "loaded" to both. Then for each "loaded" you add element `x` with class "more_space". Then for each "more_space" (there are two of them) you add '#more'

Comment: @Bullwinkle yes, in fact you always have one element with class "more_space". That's why it will be more logical to have id "more_space", not class. But it's just thoughts about logical structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what is unstable but I assume unstable means here that the new content is not getting highlighted. As the content is dynamic, use event binding on document

**$(document).on("click",".query .schedule_query_table_highlight",function(){**

Example code:

```
var Picker = function() { // This is marker script
        $(document).on("click",".query .schedule_query_table_highlight",function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "schedule_query_table_highlight") {
            $(this)

.removeClass("schedule_query_table_highlight");
            $(this).addClass("query");
        }
        else {
        $(this).removeClass("query");
        $(this).addClass("schedule_query_table_highlight");
        }
        });
};
```

Comment: Well, yes, it's one more place in OP code where dynamic elements' event handler wouldn't work. But I still hope to see fiddle with full code, because right now your answer is just a part of full answer (and we actually don't know how full answer should look like)...

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Amazing. But also i added Picker function to one more place, so the final code looks like:

`$(document).ready(function(){
 Picker();
 
    $("#more").click(function(){
  
  $(".more_space").load("inquery_ajax.php?date=" + curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date, function(){
   Picker();
  });
  
  
  Picker();`

It seems like not the cleanest code, but it works. Are there any ways to optimize it?